# Deploy spring boot app to windows server using jenkins

Tags: windows, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My current spring boot app is running in windows server 2019. Any changes to application requires manual restart, hence we want to leverage Jenkins to automate the deployments. There are plenty of examples for deploying to Linux but none available for windows. Deploying a jar from jforg to c: drive location can be done. But how do I start the app using pipeline? Any thoughts or ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to, first configure your application as a Windows service. For this, you can use a service wrapper, something like [YAJSW](https://yajsw.sourceforge.io/) or [Java Service Wrapper.](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/index.html) Then you can simply restart the service through Jenkins once the artifacts are updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any documentation available to integrate service wrapper with Jenkins? if yes, please share.

Comment: The service wrapper is for the Application. Once created using a batch step you can call the service wrapper. Read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service